# Python - Requests pulling HTML instead of JSON - 2020 edition

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to pull some exchange rate values from my bank's public API service via requests' built-in json parser. However, the following code returns HTML instead of a json response. If I put the URL in my browser, a proper json response is received. I am running python 3.6.3 on Windows 10.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

requestdate = datetime.now()

requesturl = 'https://www.isbank.com.tr/_vti_bin/DV.Isbank/PriceAndRate/PriceAndRateService.svc/GetFxRates'

payload = {'Lang': 'tr', 'fxRateType': 'INTERACTIVE', 'date': requestdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}

theheader = {
   'Accepts': 'application/json', 
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36'
   }

r = requests.get(requesturl, params=payload, headers=theheader)

received_data = r.json()["Data"]
```

The `r.text` variable holds the following:

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>\r\n<meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>\r\n<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="/>\r\n\r\n<script>\r\n\r\n(function(){\r\nwindow["bobcmn"] = "111110101010102000000022000000052000000002257e5d0f200000096300000000300000000300000006/TSPD/300000008TSPD_101300000005https3000000b008d71b590fab2000505c395556f07e0e931c104e72c02f7263ef18b3b4008bfc8d00602baa984f6208848a2bb30a2800bcc38dda75b9810c1d79afa859034c2fe90f88f6031a55aa21de789d6c5feb34f723079ceb7b7d39200000000200000000";\r\n\r\nwindow.lEQ=!!window.lEQ;try{(function(){(function(){var _=-1,_={I:++_,oi:"false"[_],l:++_,Lz:"false"[_],il:++_,lll:"[object Object]"[_],zZ:(_[_]+"")[_],Oz:++_,OZ:"true"[_],zl:++_,Il:++_,Oi:"[object Object]"[_],i:++_,oL:++_,oSl:++_,LSl:++_};try{_.lz=(_.lz=_+"")[_.Il]+(_.oO=_.lz[_.l])+(_.Li=(_.LO+"")[_.l])+(!_+"")[_.Oz]+(_.OO=_.lz[_.i])+(_.LO="true"[_.l])+(_.SZ="true"[_.il])+_.lz[_.Il]+_.OO+_.oO+_.LO,_.Li=_.LO+"true"[_.Oz]+_.OO+_.SZ+_.LO+_.Li,_.LO=_.I[_.lz][_.lz],_.LO(_.LO(_.Li+\'"\\\\\'+_.l+_.Il+_.l+_.oi+"\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"("+_.OO+"\\\\"+_.l+_.oL+\n_.l+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.I+_.OZ+_.oO+_.oi+"\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.oL+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.l+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.i+_.zZ+_.oO+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.oL+"[\'\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.I+_.Lz+"\\\\"+_.l+_.oL+_.l+"false"[_.il]+_.oO+_.Lz+_.zZ+"\']\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"===\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"\'\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.Oz+_.OO+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.il+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.l+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.i+"\\\\"+_.l+_.zl+_.oL+"\')\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"{\\\\"+_.l+_.il+"\\\\"+_.l+_.l+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.i+_.Lz+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.il+"\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+_.OZ+_.zZ+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.i+_.Oi+"\\\\"+_.l+_.oL+_.l+_.SZ+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.il+\n"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.Oz+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.I+"\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"=\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.oL+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.l+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.i+_.zZ+_.oO+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.oL+"[\'\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.I+_.Lz+"\\\\"+_.l+_.oL+_.l+"false"[_.il]+_.oO+_.Lz+_.zZ+"\'].\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.il+_.OZ+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.I+"false"[_.il]+_.Lz+_.Oi+_.OZ+"(/.{"+_.l+","+_.zl+"}/\\\\"+_.l+_.zl+_.oL+",\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+_.oi+_.SZ+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.i+_.Oi+_.OO+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.l+_.oO+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.i+"\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"(\\\\"+_.l+_.oL+_.I+")\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"{\\\\"+_.l+_.il+"\\\\"+_.l+_.l+\n"\\\\"+_.l+_.l+"\\\\"+_.l+_.l+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.il+_.OZ+_.OO+_.SZ+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.il+"\\\\"+_.l+_.Il+_.i+"\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"(\\\\"+_.l+_.oL+_.I+"\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"+\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+"\\\\"+_.l+_.oL+_.I+").\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.Oz+_.SZ+_.lll+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.Oz+_.OO+"\\\\"+_.l+_.i+_.il+"("+_.il+",\\\\"+_.zl+_.I+_.zl+")\\\\"+_.l+_.il+"\\\\"+_.l+_.l+"\\\\"+_.l+_.l+"});\\\\"+_.l+_.il+"}\\\\"+_.l+_.il+\'"\')())()}catch(J){_%=5}})();var i_=78;\ntry{var l_,o_,Z_=I(15)?1:0,s_=I(594)?1:0,_i=I(281)?1:0,ii=I(740)?0:1,Ii=I(887)?0:1,Oi=I(325)?1:0,si=I(776)?0:1,iI=I(460)?1:0;for(var II=(I(322),0);II<o_;++II)Z_+=I(51)?2:1,s_+=(I(649),2),_i+=I(610)?2:1,ii+=(I(816),2),Ii+=I(797)?1:2,Oi+=I(49)?2:1,si+=I(107)?2:1,iI+=(I(383),3);l_=Z_+s_+_i+ii+Ii+Oi+si+iI;window.sZ===l_&&(window.sZ=++l_)}catch(JI){window.sZ=l_}var lI=!0;function l(_,J){_+=J;return _.toString(36)}\nfunction LI(_){var J=14;!_||document[O(J,132,119,129,119,112,119,122,119,130,135,97,130,111,130,115)]&&document[z(J,132,119,129,119,112,119,122,119,130,135,97,130,111,130,115)]!==O(J,132,119,129,119,112,122,115)||(lI=!1);return lI}function z(_){var J=arguments.length,L=[];for(var s=1;s<J;++s)L.push(arguments[s]-_);return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,L)}function O(_){var J=arguments.length,L=[],s=1;while(s<J)L[s-1]=arguments[s++]-_;return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,L)}function SI(){}\nLI(window[SI[O(i_,188,175,187,179)]]===SI);LI(typeof ie9rgb4!==l(1242178186121,i_));LI(RegExp("\\x3c")[l(1372127,i_)](function(){return"\\x3c"})&!RegExp(l(42811,i_))[l(1372127,i_)](function(){return"\'x3\'+\'d\';"}));\nvar ij=window[z(i_,175,194,194,175,177,182,147,196,179,188,194)]||RegExp(O(i_,187,189,176,183,202,175,188,178,192,189,183,178),l(-60,i_))[O(i_,194,179,193,194)](window["\\x6e\\x61vi\\x67a\\x74\\x6f\\x72"]["\\x75\\x73e\\x72A\\x67\\x65\\x6et"]),Ij=+new Date+(I(151)?6E5:569976),jj,Jj,lj,Oj=window[O(i_,193,179,194,162,183,187,179,189,195,194)],zj=ij?I(678)?31457:3E4:I(421)?6E3:4585;\ndocument[O(i_,175,178,178,147,196,179,188,194,154,183,193,194,179,188,179,192)]&&document[O(i_,175,178,178,147,196,179,188,194,154,183,193,194,179,188,179,192)](O(i_,196,183,193,183,176,183,186,183,194,199,177,182,175,188,181,179),function(_){var J=12;document[z(J,130,117,127,117,110,117,120,117,128,133,95,128,109,128,113)]&&(document[z(J,130,117,127,117,110,117,120,117,128,133,95,128,109,128,113)]===O(J,116,117,112,112,113,122)&&_[O(J,117,127,96,126,129,127,128,113,112)]?lj=!0:document[z(J,130,117,\n127,117,110,117,120,117,128,133,95,128,109,128,113)]===l(68616527654,J)&&(jj=+new Date,lj=!1,sj()))});function sj(){if(!document[O(90,203,207,191,204,211,173,191,198,191,189,206,201,204)])return!0;var _=+new Date;if(_>Ij&&(I(592)?6E5:467242)>_-jj)return LI(!1);var J=LI(Jj&&!lj&&jj+zj<_);jj=_;Jj||(Jj=!0,Oj(function(){Jj=!1},I(125)?1:0));return J}sj();var Sj=[I(51)?17795081:18390932,I(130)?27611931586:2147483647,I(517)?1558153217:1955737085];\nfunction jJ(_){var J=5;_=typeof _===z(J,120,121,119,110,115,108)?_:_[O(J,121,116,88,121,119,110,115,108)](I(942)?34:36);var L=window[_];if(!L[z(J,121,116,88,121,119,110,115,108)])return;var s=""+L;window[_]=function(_,J){Jj=!1;return L(_,J)};window[_][z(J,121,116,88,121,119,110,115,108)]=function(){return s}}for(var JJ=(I(979),0);JJ<Sj[l(1294399127,i_)];++JJ)jJ(Sj[JJ]);LI(!1!==window[z(i_,186,147,159)]);window.Zs={iS:"08db3c215f017800c95fcb89d8f5022feb931e00baa5d03c9d2b489b10395feca92925bc45a63637cbc3827ddbed83c42d750e2b9c814a433ec0f264a2e87032376d2d04e3aa604193ca130913c32f725829241f7ff499463909f095ae09264210c33f3d9ba40c02d9e93b569a89c69aca1323a45369182ec2972612e5589060"};\nfunction lJ(_){var J=+new Date,L;!document[O(13,126,130,114,127,134,96,114,121,114,112,129,124,127,78,121,121)]||J>Ij&&(I(860)?553817:6E5)>J-jj?L=LI(!1):(L=LI(Jj&&!lj&&jj+zj<J),jj=J,Jj||(Jj=!0,Oj(function(){Jj=!1},I(687)?0:1)));return!(arguments[_]^L)}function I(_){return 639>_}(function(_){_||setTimeout(function(){var _=setTimeout(function(){},250);for(var L=0;L<=_;++L)clearTimeout(L)},500)})(!0);})();}catch(x){}finally{ie9rgb4=void(0);};function ie9rgb4(a,b){return a>>b>>0};\n\r\n})();\r\n\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/TSPD/08d71b590fab200073f723eefb2859c773f4a9738c93cff6c057edec60af8de9d1e847346bd23db9?type=7"></script>\r\n<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.<br/>Your support ID is:   562830526560985430.</noscript>\r\n</head><body>\r\n</body></html>'
```

and the `r.headers` returns the following:

```
{'P3P': 'CP="{}"', 'Content-Length': '6549', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
```

Comment: I think problem not in your code. Url does not return json even if you specify content type and accept headers.

Answer (score 1):

You are being blocked by their JS protection:

[Website log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWMjL.png)

To see how the website works you can go to DevTools (Ctrl + Shift + U -> GoogleChrome), and then Network (enable preserve log)

You need to figure out which one of these headers are needed:

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hr;q=0.8,sr;q=0.7,bs;q=0.6,de;q=0.5',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': host,
    'Referer': previous_link,
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'request-id': '92dc449f-8b6d-9027-b881-98248fb6918b',
    'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=20736000',
    'Cookie': cookies
}
```

The JS that is blocking you is at this link: 
https://www.isbank.com.tr/TSPD/08d71b590fab200021f1f242cb7dd568317cb8edc1ba5a81730ea8c6f901eddf8781c27aa09e5c81?type=7

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you... This is very helpful. Do you think rendering it with requests-html would work? I am trying to get the `r.html.render()` to work as documented here https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/, but running into more problems than solutions...

Comment: `r.html.render()` will not help you here as JS does not return the json, its just sets up the cookies you use in the 3 request.
1) You go to the page( this trigers the JS protection as you don't have the cookies that you need)
2) it redirects you to the JS page and makes those Cookies
3) uses the cookies and sends you the page at 1)  where you receive the json.
If speed is not relay an issue for you, you can use something like selenium or similar. And if that is not an option you would need to simulate generating of those cookies somehow, try hard coding them mby they are always the same.

Comment: So why wouldn't a `HTMLSession` not create the required cookies?

`r = session.get(requesturl, params=payload)`